# Android 10 Dual Selfie camera regression?

Tags: android, android-camera2, android-10.0

We use Pixel 3XL's dual selfie cameras in our app (app is specifically designed for Google's Pixel 3XL phone).

All was good, we made use of wide and tele(normal) cameras in the front, and things worked fine.

Then Android 10 upgrade came, and the same code is now producing images from "wide" and "normal" cameras that are identical in terms of FOV. In other words, wide and tele cameras see the same angle (except wide angle lens is quite a bit softer than normal lens, which is understandable, as the normal lens has optical auto-focus and wide is a fixed focal length).

We tried different samples and different code paths, java and kotlin, does not matter. Same exact sample code that just shows previews of normal and wide lens next to each other

On Android 9 - those are vastly different
On Android 10 (API 29) - identical in terms of FOV

Tried on different physical devices, asked others to try on theirs - 100% consistent. No matter what the app is - dual selfie camera wide angle cam code is not compatible.

What are we missing? Is there any setting we should use on A10 that was on by default on A9?

Comment: Maybe you have to put `brokenApi` back to `false`. (I am really sorry)

Comment: See [also](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59806590/android-10-api-29-camera2-api-regression-with-wide-angle-camera)

Comment: Yep, identical issue. No takers. Surprised an issue like this has not shown up for many others.

Comment: @user2349195 did you find a solution? I'm also trying to find it https://stackoverflow.com/a/66569731/7767664