# detect all cameras android

Tags: java, android, camera, android-camera2

I have a app that uses the Camera2 API to get a preview of the camera.
I want to choose between the lens of my phone.
In my code I am using the following code:

```
CameraManager manager = (CameraManager) activity.getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);
String[] ids = manager.getCameraIdList();
```

When I use my galaxy s10 that have 2 front facing cameras (regular and wide) and 3 rear facing cameras I only get 4 ids back from the manager:

```
0- regular rear
1- regular front
2- wide rear
3- wide front
```

why I don't get the 3 rear macro camera.

the problems appear in all of my phones that have more then 1 camera facing back

how can I get all of the rear cameras?

tnx ahead

Answer (score 2):

As per the documentation you are getting only the logical cameras.

```
public String[] getCameraIdList ()

Return the list of currently connected camera devices by identifier, including cameras that may be in use by other camera API clients.
Non-removable cameras use integers starting at 0 for their identifiers, while removable cameras have a unique identifier for each individual device, even if they are the same model.
This list doesn't contain physical cameras that can only be used as part of a logical multi-camera device.

Returns
String[]    The list of currently connected camera devices. This value cannot be null.
```

To get the physical cameras, use this

[image]
[image]
[image]

REFERENCES:

https://source.android.com/devices/camera/multi-camera

[Camera2 replacing one logical stream with two physical streams in Android API 29](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55923506/camera2-replacing-one-logical-stream-with-two-physical-streams-in-android-api-29)

Answer (score 0):

I find out that on some devices not all the cameras are returned in `manager.getCameraIdList();` You can try to get CameraCharacteristics using `cameraManager.getCameraCharacteristics(cameraId);` with some ids from predefined list of possible camera IDs, something like this:  `String[] possibleCameraIDs = {"0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8"};`

Comment: when adding it to the program it immediately crashes when choosing lens that is not given also by the `manager.getCameraIdList();`